# Is it possible to disable force shutdown from the power button?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro Mid 2012 and I would like to know if is possible to disable the "force shutdown by pressing the power button for 5 seconds".

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to disable the force shutdown, it is hardwired, and the interrupt cycle runs continuously checking for it.